# Bit operations and the == vs != operator

Tags: python, algorithm, bitwise-operators

I'm doing some Leetcode problems and I came across a weird problem:

```
for i in range(32):
        if(n&mask == 1):
            bits +=1
        mask <<=1
    return bits
```

This doesn't work. Now if instead of comparing if it is equal to one do the condition when it's different than 0, it works.

```
for i in range(32):
        if(n&mask != 0):
            bits +=1
        mask <<=1
    return bits
```

Aren't they doing the same thing in a different way? Shouldn't the answer be the same? The questions in the following (https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-1-bits/description/)

Comment: if `n = 1101` and `mask = 1010` then `n&mask == 1000`. This is not zero, but its also not one.

Comment: Oh, got it now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not the same, as you discovered. As obvious as it sounds, `==1` checks if the value is 1, `!=0` check if the value is different from 0. What you are probably missing is that values other than 1 and 0 are possible.

`a&b` returns the bitwise and of 2 integers: `1&1 == 1`, but `2&2 == 2`, and thus `2&2 != 0`, but is not 1.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between `and , or , not`   and `& , | , !`

and  , or , not are logical operators and `& , | , !` are bitwise operators.

`x or y` : if x is false then y , else x

`x and y` : if x is false then x , else y

`not x` : if x is false then true else false

Shortcut :

`x and y` : always gives y if both are not false

`x or y` : always gives x if both are not false

> What is actually false ?

From python official doc :

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following
>   values are considered false:
>
> - None
> - False
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
> - any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
> - any empty mapping, for example, {}.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a **nonzero**() or **len**() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.2.5
> - All other values are considered true -- so objects of many types are always true.

Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return 0 or False for false and 1 or True for true, unless otherwise stated. (Important exception: the Boolean operations "or" and "and" always return one of their operands.)

Now what are bitwise operators?

Bitwise operators work on bit manipulation and addition :

| operator is not addition ( it perform addition basis on truth table)
& operator is not multiplication (it perform multiplication basis on truth table)

5 | 3  =>  101 | 011 = 111  which is 7 in decimal

5 & 3 =>   101 & 011 = 001 which is 1

You can check these in python terminal